# Can't get my sidebar on the right of content?

Tags: html, css, alignment, dreamweaver, sidebar

I have a webpage, and it has two divs inside the container- `content` and `sidebar1`. I don't know why, but whenever I place my `sidebar1` div on the right, after the `content` div, I land up with my sidebar underneath, not next to it!

## My code:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h1><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Heading" -->Heading<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></h1>
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Content" -->Just some
    <!-- end .content -->
    dummy text.<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
    <div class="sidebar1">
    </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer text<!--end .footer --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
```

### CSS

```
.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 950px;
    float: left;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

I'm still very new to HTML, and don't understand my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EUtwK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is 10px smaller than the parent so there is no room for a 192px sidebar next to it (20% of 960px).

You could do something more like this:

```css
#container {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background: #dff;
}

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fdd;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will float the sidebar to the right of the container and then the content div will take up any of the remaining space in the container. The `overflow: hidden` tells the div to take note of the floated element when deciding on the size instead of just taking up the full width of the container. For this to work you MUST have the floated elements before the `overflow: hidden` element.

Comment: I liked your answer most, just because it has the best explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float: left` for your `.sidebar1`, or reorder your HTML so that the sidebar comes before the content.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have three `<div>`s inside your container, I don't know if that was intentional. And you should give your `.content` a `width: 80%;`.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that your elements are too wide for the container. Either put your sidebar inside .content, or adjust your widths. Here's one option:

http://jsfiddle.net/cKMa2/2

```
.sidebar1 {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 78%;
    float: left;
    border-left-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #FFF;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer {
    clear: both;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar1">Some content Some content Some content</div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Heading</h1>

        <p>Just some dummy text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your elements are floating in a resizable window, so when there is not enough space the floated elements go to the next line.

There is an easy solution: put the floating elements in a container with a fixed width wide enough to contain all of the floated boxes.

I'm not sure of the dimensions of your screen, but for example, this could work:

```
<div style="width: 1300px;">
    (Put the floated boxes here)
<div>
```